# Which nuts are typically paired with raspberry and white chocolate?

Tags: dessert, nuts, raspberries

I repeat: Which nuts go well with raspberry and white chocolate?

I was just wondering about typical combinations that are known to go well with raspberry and white chocolate. Like regular chocolate and hazelnuts. Or tomato and basil. I don't believe that these known combinations are opinion-based.

More context: I've made a simple version of [raspberry cake pops](http://www.howtocookthat.net/public_html/raspberry-white-chocolate-cake-pops-recipe/) and I want to sprinkle some kind of a nut on top.

Comment: We don't have a lot to go on here.  For what applications?  What have you tried already?  What hasn't worked in your previous efforts?  Are there specific restrictions (such as allergies) on what type of nuts you can have?  Questions that only ask for opinions don't tend to last very long here.

Comment: almonds.... I'd say more in an answer but I don't know why or what else to suggest

Comment: Sorry, but pairing questions are off topic. They are a cultural preference and so fall squarely into the "opinion based" closing reason.

Comment: @rumtscho As you know I'm still learning. Would the question work if it was worded as "In dessert recipes, which nuts are most often used with raspberries and white chocolate?" Also, the first line of the content (I repeat ...) could be removed. I wanted to ask and use this to learn rather than just try to edit.

Comment: @CindyAskew I understand that our rules can seem strange at the beginning, because we do close many questions which are interesting for cooks. What we want to do here is focus on very efficient sharing of reliable information. And there are some types of question where our voting system produces unwanted results. For example flavor pairings: what "goes well with X" is a matter of personal experience, people tend to like combinations they have encountered frequently. It might seem objective if everybody around you has the same preferences (because the combination is frequent in your home...

Comment: ... cuisine), but it is in fact terribly subjective. "What is a 'typical' pairing" is a question which is, in its root, objective - if somebody cared to do the research and actually count thousands of recipes from different cultures (and it has been done for a few ingredients). But most people are not aware of such research, and will just upvote the answers they are familiar with, such that the voting will be skewed by our audience's culture. The second problem is that it will produce a list where no answer is the best one, and we specialize in questions whose solutions can be clearly ranked.

Comment: Last but not least, the OP can never really choose a best answer - it is not that they can try out the answers and find which is the one which "works". All these factors make the pairing questions very poor candidates, similar to all other poll-like questions. Pairing itself is more of a grey area than other poll-like questions, and we have discussed them before, but found no way to actually make them work well, unless it was a diferent question (where the cook has a very specific purpose) worded as pairing. See following Meta links:

Comment: See http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1091/should-what-can-i-add-to-x-questions-be-closed-by-default, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/should-we-close-questions-structured-like-what-compliments-does-not-work-with/1646#1646, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/can-i-ask-about-recipe-modification-or-flavor-pairings, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/how-can-we-make-pairing-questions-work for the existing dicussion on the topic.

Comment: @rumtscho I am starting to get a much better understanding of what questions can be asked and how to phrase them so that they better fit the parameters of the site. I truly appreciate all of your help with this. In my previous comment I asked if the question could be worded in a different way, example provided, so it would be acceptable to our standard. Can you give me feedback on that? I acceptable cn u tell me if it is okay for me to edit or if

Comment: Sorry. Last sentence should have read "if acceptable can you tell if if it is okay for me to edit or if you need to.

Comment: @CindyAskew OK, sorry for burrying my answer in so much other information. To the point: If we reworded it per your suggestion, it would still remain a pairing question. Pairing questions are considered too subjective to work on our site. So it wouldn't help to reopen the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as flavor profiles go, almonds and macadamia nuts work well. But my all time favorite is hazelnuts (filberts).

I have heard of recipes that call for pecans. While I absolutely love pecans I haven't tried them with raspberry and white chocolate. I would like to say the flavor combination should  be good but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: +1, macadamia or almond is very typical. I can't say that I've seen pecans with white chocolate and berries though.

Comment: +1, macadamia is what instantly sprung to my mind as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Pistachios** would go really well with those.

and now I want to make cookies...