# I am wondering if certain ingredients go together

Tags: carrots, spinach

I am making Spinach an Pea soup and would like to know if adding some grated carrots to it would be good?

Comment: Oh yes, the grated carrots are practically a requirement in this household.

Comment: Carrots in general tend to be a little sweet, so adding some may counter some of the bitterness that spinach can developed if cooked too much.  It shouldn't hurt to add them.

Comment: Hello Patty! Our site functions differently from what you might be accustomed to. We only do objective questions, and what goes together is a matter of personal taste. See the discussion in the comments of this old question for details. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46208/which-nuts-are-typically-paired-with-raspberry-and-white-chocolate. Sorry we couldn't help - really, the only way to know if this is a pairing *you* find tasty is to try and decide whether you like it.

Comment: Being objective would have not caused this question to be put on hold.  Peas and carrots go well together - grated  carrots are often called for in split pea soup and The Flavor Bible (book) highlights their use together.